# QT Creator C configuration

Tags: c, qt-creator

I have been enjoying using Qt Creator for bare C development, however the IDE still seems to think that 'class' is a keyword. This creates some issues with autocompletion/intellisense, as struct members named 'class' are not listed.

I thought the answer would be in the 'c.xml' generic highlighter file in my home directory, but this file does not even list 'class' as a valid keyword and I have set the priority of this highlighter file to 100 (high).

Does anyone know how to configure Qt Creator to treat C source/header files as C and not C++ with regard to the 'class' keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs already reported: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-12817, https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-9125. Just comment there and get some developer attention and ask about workarounds(seems needs recompiling).